# 'firebase.auth is not a function' error after SDK update

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the Firebase JS sdk for the web without any problems for a year now. After updating my code from the version `5.3.1` to use the latest `6.5.0` SDK version, I got the below error:

```
TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function
```

I know what the message means, but I don't really understand why I get it. I checked the firebase documentation and the functions and method names remained the same.

Here is my old solution:

```
// HTML
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
// JS
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",

};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const email = txtEmail.value;
const pass = txtPassword.value;
const auth = firebase.auth();


firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;


        if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
          showAlert(errorMessage, 'Error!');
        }
        if (errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          showAlert(errorMessage, 'Error!');
        }
        if (errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email') {
          showAlert(errorMessage, 'Error!');
        }
        else {
          // alert(errorMessage);
          //alert(error);
        }
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if (firebaseUser) {


          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          url: "/user/",
          data: JSON.stringify({""),
          success: function(data) {

          },
           async: false
          });
```

And these are the changed parts of the code which doesn't work:

```
// HTML
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
// JS
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appid: "...."
};
```

Only the version number changed to 6.5.0 and the appid has been added to the config variable. Before the update I didn't have any appid's, I assume it's related to a new Firebase feature or something like that.

My question is that did something change with initalization of the SDK, like more SDK's should be linked? Or did the JS function names changed? I don't understand the whole situation as everything worked fine until I changed the SDK version, so there must be something with the new SDK.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) (Tab "From the CDN"), importing `firebase-app.js` only is not sufficient: you need, in addition, to import all the libraries of the Firebase products you want to use (Firebase Auth, Firestore, etc...).

So, in your case, you should do as follows:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/X.Y.Z/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/X.Y.Z/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

where `X.Y.Z` is the version number of the libraries, i.e. 6.6.1 at the time of writing.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be pointed out to Google since this solved my issue and they instruct in their documentation to use `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-app.js"></script>`.